# Why copied index is so much smaller than the original one?

Tags: java, bash, elasticsearch

I've backuped the Elastic Search index with the *[elasticsearch-dump](https://hub.docker.com/r/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump/)* tool, but for some reason it's much smaller than the original one. The number of Lucene documents per index is the same.

The original one is 145 GB, the copied one is 102 GB. The original one is from the production environment, so it was heavily used.

I used commands:

```
docker run --name=elasticsearch-dump --rm -i taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump elasticdump \
       --input=books \
       --output=books-backup \
       --type=mapping

docker run --name=elasticsearch-dump --rm -i taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump elasticdump \
       --input=books \
       --output=books-backup \
       --type=data \
       --limit=1000
```

What's the reason of the difference? How should I copy the index to keep all the data? Or maybe it's the cache or temporary data, which is not needed at all?

Elasticsearch version is 6.8.8. An application adding data to the original index is written in Java.

Comment: where there any deleted documents in the original?

Comment: Yes, couple of millions.